# python 3, what is the best way to run different loops simultaneously?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, while-loop

I have a socket server, so it is looping forever and check whatever data received on the socket.
If b'Go' command is received on the socket connection, I want to start another loop that prints "Going ..." every 5 seconds.
If b'Stop' command is received on the socket connection, I want to start another loop that prints "Sitting ..." once.
Then the socket connection keep listening.

I tried the following but now blocked. Thanks for help.

```
import socket
import threading
import time

class SimpleServer:
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.host = socket.getfqdn()
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.settimeout(None)
        self.client_sockets = []

    def initialise(self):
        try:
            self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        except socket.error:
            return
        self.sock.listen(5)
        self.server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.serve_forever)
        self.server_thread.setDaemon(True)
        self.server_thread.start()

    def serve_forever(self):
        try:
            request, client_address = self.sock.accept()
            with request:
                while True:
                    data = request.recv(1024)
                    if not data:
                        break

                    data = data.decode("utf-8").strip()
                    if data == 'Go':
                        # Start another thread to print "Going ..." every 1 minute 
                        # without blocking receiving new data on the socket
                        # prevent using subprocess.call if possible
                        ????????
                    elif data == 'Stop':
                        print('Sitting ...')
        except socket.error:
            return



if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = SimpleServer(args.socket_port)
    server.initialise()
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Check out the [`socketserver` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html) of the standard library

Comment: Are you intentionally calling `serve_forever` in both the main and child thread? It seems like the last line is an error.

Comment: for some reason it seems that the program will not enter the loop if I do not have the last line

Comment: You've set the server thread to be a deamon.  Without preventing the main thread from exiting, the daemon thread exits when the main thread exits.  You don't want a second server_forever(), but something like `input('hit enter to stop the server')`.  This will provide a way to kill the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.  Just make a function to perform the work and make more threads.  For example:

```py
import socket
import threading
import time

class SimpleServer:
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket()

    def initialise(self):
        self.sock.bind(('', self.port))
        self.sock.listen()
        self.server_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.serve_forever,daemon=True)
        self.server_thread.start()
        self.run = False                  # Track running Go thread

    def worker(self):                     # Go thread worker
        while self.run:
            print(' Go',end='',flush=True)
            time.sleep(1)

    def serve_forever(self):
        client, client_address = self.sock.accept()

        # Wrap socket in a file-like object.  TCP is not a message-based protocol
        # so you have to delimit messages in some manner.  I'm using newline
        # To indicate end-of-message.
        request = client.makefile('r',encoding='utf8')

        with client,request:  # To ensure socket and makefile wrapper close
            while True:
                data = request.readline()  # Read to newline for a message
                if not data:
                    break

                data = data.strip()
                if data == 'Go' and not self.run:
                    self.run = True
                    self.worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.worker,daemon=True)
                    self.worker_thread.start()
                elif data == 'Stop':
                    self.run = False
                    self.worker_thread.join()
                    print(' Sitting ...')

def client():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(('localhost',5000))
    s.sendall(b'Go\n')
    time.sleep(5)
    s.sendall(b'Stop\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = SimpleServer(5000)
    server.initialise()
    t = threading.Thread(target=client,daemon=True)
    t.start()

    # All threads are daemons, and will terminate if main thread exits.
    input('hit enter to quit server...')
```

Output:

```
hit enter to quit server... Go Go Go Go Go Sitting ...
```

Comment: That helped, Thanks.
I removed the client part as the client is running somewhere else ;o)

Comment: @wolfguru client was just added to make a standalone working example.